# Can i compare a column in a table to a variable of type cursor?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor

I declared a cursor to iterate on my employee ids.

```
DECLARE
    r_employee employee.id%type;
c_employee CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        distinct employee_id
    FROM
        employee;
```

Then i used this cursor to select fields in another table "branch" where the employee_id in "branch" table matches the cursor.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    employee_id
FROM
    branch
WHERE
    branch.employee_id = r_employee 

GROUP BY
    employee_id
```

the following error is appearing:

> ERROR:  column "r_employee" does not exist.

the above code is inside a loop that fetches r_employee from c_employee at each loop.
Any clue how to fix this? (using postgresql)

Comment: Why two SELECT's? JOIN the tables and get all wanted data with just one SELECT.

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: To find the cause of your error, I'd need to see the whole code, or at least more than I see now.

Comment: the code has a lot more to it but the main issue is here only because thats where im using "r_employee" no where else.

Comment: and no i cant join tables because as i said the code has a lot more to it. I need to loop over the table and perform certain actions for each employee id. That's why im using the cursor

Comment: the code lines i posted are from the beginning of the code so the rest does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO you cannot. You must refer to a column within the cursor not to a cursor itself. A cursor contains the results of a query whether the query returns a single column or multiple columns. In this case your declaration of r_employee essentially is a record containing a single variable. But single column or multiple you must refer to the column name within the cursor, or the record you fetched the cursor into.  So

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    employee_id
FROM
    branch
WHERE
    branch.employee_id = r_employee.id   --<< reference the variable within the record >>

GROUP BY
    employee_id;
```